# How do you create file with a variable in C++?

Tags: c++

I was wondering how to put a variable where `"example.txt"` is below:

```
ofstream file;
file.open ("example.txt");
```

Answer (score 16):

just put a variable there :-P

if you use `std::string` then you need to get the `const char*` using `.c_str()` so your options are:

```
const char *filename = "example.txt"
file.open(filename);
```

or:

```
std::string filename = "example.txt"
file.open(filename.c_str());
```

Comment: Ah I see what you are sayin, but should I make the variable bold?

Comment: @Hamish filename variables are supposed to be in italic Times New Roman 10pt. Bold filename variables may be supported as a compiler extension, but it's nonstandard.

Comment: ... is this an August Fools' joke or something?

Comment: With C++11, you can pass a `std::string` to `file.open` without using `.c_str()`